# How to partially apply a function with desired order in Elm?

Tags: function, elm, partial-application

Suppose I have a function that takes 3 parameters as input. How to partially apply this function in Elm so it takes first and last parameters and waits for the second parameter to return the final result?

This can be done in [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com/) with `R.__` which is named `placeholer`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just wrap it in a lambda function that has the shape you want, which is what would be produced by any other means anyway:

```
\y -> f "x" y "z"
```

In a curried language I find the need to do this so rare that adding syntax sugar specifically for this use case seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

As glennsl says, you can wrap your function in another function with the argument order that you want. his answer assumes that you know statically what the first and third arguments are, if you don't, but just want to partially apply the first and third argument, then apply the second you can take a function like,

```
joinThree : String -> String -> String -> String
joinThree first second third =
        first ++ second ++ third
```

and wrap it in a new function that calls the first function, but with a different argument order,

```
joinThreeWrapper : String -> String -> String -> String
joinThreeWrapper first third second =
    joinThree first second third
```

This allows you to call this function like,

```
welcomeToNeverland : String -> String
welcomeToNeverland name =
    let
        myGreeting = joinThreeWrapper "Welcome " " to Neverland"
    in
        myGreeting name
```

Then you can use it like,

```
text (welcomeToNeverland "Wendy")
-- Welcome Wendy to Neverland
```

Writing `joinThreeWrapper` like this makes it a bit easier to map your function over a list like,

```
greetMany : List String -> List String
greetMany names =
    List.map (joinThreeWrapper "Welcome " ", this is our town. ") names
```

so that you can do,

```
text (List.map (++) (greetMany ["Jesse", "Carl"]))
-- Welcome Jesse, this is our town. Welcome Carl, this is our town.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [flip](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/Basics#flip) from the core Basics module.

For instance:

```
> append3 x y z = x ++ y ++ z
<function> : appendable -> appendable -> appendable -> appendable
> hello = flip (append3 "Hello, ") "!"
<function> : String -> String
> hello "world"
"Hello, world!" : String
```

Comment: This is a nice solution where parameters are few.

Comment: @kaskelotti you're correct. [`flip` was removed in 0.19](https://github.com/elm/compiler/blob/master/upgrade-docs/0.19.md#functions-removed) in favor of named helper functions.